# Angular 2 Session Timeout (or equivalent)

Tags: angular, session, timeout

Does Angular 2/4/5 have the concept of something similar to HTTP Session Timeouts in Java?

I have an Angular 2 application that embeds another application through an IFrame.  There are times a user can be performing tasks in the embedded application for over an hour and when they go back to my Angular 2 application, they are no longer logged in because their credentials are no longer in memory.

What mechanism does Angular 2/4/5 use to specify how long user sessions are active for and is there a setting to change that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you researched or try any approach that you can share on your post?  Please provide any code or error console so that you can get a proper answer.  Regards.

Comment: The fundamental question I have is how do you control how long a user's session is before all of the in-memory objects are destroyed.  Is there a configuration setting to change the session length.

I basically need my user to be able to come back to my application after over an hour and resume where they left off.  Right now, all objects in memory are being destroyed so the user reverts to an unauthenticated state and they have to log back in.